# Calculating noise floor level and SNR

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

I have N samples of a baseband IQ signal that I took from an SDR (Pluto) with a certain fs (BW = fs).
How can I accurately calculate the noise floor level of that signal in dBm, SNR in dB and Peak To Noise Ratio in Matlab

Comment: better forum for this is likely the *Signal Processing* stack ... https://dsp.stackexchange.com/